# Perl - Circular Dependency Check in XML/HoH

Tags: xml, perl, graph, circular-dependency

I am trying to build a batch/workflow script with a sample workflow definition as follows.

```
<project id="1" name="Project One" desc="" status="">
    <module id="11" name="Module Eleven" desc="" status="">
        <group id="101" name="Group 101" desc ="" status="" skip="false">
            <task id="1001" type="Shell" priority="10" desc="" author="" added="" modified="" status="" skip="false">
                <predecessors ref="1002" />
                <program folder="." object="test.pl" />
                <arguments value="job1 10 0" />
            </task>
            <task id="1002" type="Shell" priority="10" desc="" author="" added="" modified="" status="" skip="false">
                <predecessors ref="1003" />
                <program folder="." object="test.pl" />
                <arguments value="job2 5 0" />
            </task>
            <task id="1003" type="Shell" priority="10" desc="" author="" added="" modified="" status="" skip="false">
                <predecessors ref="1001" />
                <program folder="." object="test.pl" />
                <arguments value="job3 15 0" />
            </task>
        </group>
    </module>
</project>
```

I have used XML::Simple to convert the XML into a hash of hashes.

I am searching for an efficient logic to detect circular dependencies in XML or HoH.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your code that converts to a hash of hashes?

Comment: `my $xml = new XML::Simple;`
`my $data = $xml->XMLin($list);`

Comment: I am thinking of walking through the hashes, saving every task into a dictionary, and checking whether I have encountered a key already. This also helps me implement a logic to validate whether there is a duplicate task id.

Comment: do tasks always have a single predecessor? If not how do you express it? Is it with  several `predecessors` elements, or with space separated values in the `ref` attribute, or some other way?

Comment: The tasks may have multiple predecessors. Multiple <predecessor> tags can be accessed as a list in XML::Simple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use Graph       qw( );
use XML::LibXML qw( );

my ($xml_qfn) = @ARGV
   or die "usage\n";

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($xml_qfn);

my %seen_task_ids;
my $task_dep_graph = Graph->new();

for my $task_node ($doc->findnodes('/project/module/group/task')) {
   my $id = $task_node->getAttribute('id');
   die("Duplicate task id $id\n") if $seen_task_ids{$id}++;

   my @deps =
      map $_->getAttribute('ref'),
       $task_node->findnodes('predecessors');

   $task_dep_graph->add_edge($id, $_) for @deps;
}

if (my @cycle = $task_dep_graph->find_a_cycle()) {
   die("Task dependency cycle @cycle\n");
}
```

Comment: Amazing. You just made things a whole lot easier. I had a feeling that graph is the way to go from all googling around I did. I guess I would probably build the rest of the logic using graph module. Moreover, there are no dependencies for graph module outside core modules.